# intel xdk application development splash screen of intel html5 coustomization

Tags: intel, intel-xdk

When I create an application, the starting window is intel html5 and the logo is also displayed as intel html5. I just want to remove intel xdk html 5 splash screen when I execute my application in device. I am using android devices.
Is there any java script file or any other function to remove or customize the starting window of my application. This is my current Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function insert(){
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
 var nam = document.getElementById("Tname").value;
 var id = document.getElementById("Tid").value;
 var name2 = "velocity";
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS APP (id unique, log)');
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO APP (id, log) VALUES (?,?)',[id,nam]);
  //tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (61,'+name2+')');
  msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
  document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  msg;
});
}
function readdata(){
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var id = document.getElementById("Tid").value;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM APP', [], function (tx, results) {
  console.log("All rows:");
   var len = results.rows.length, i;
   msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
   document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
     msg = "<p><b>Name :-" + results.rows.item(i).log +"<br/>Contact :-" +results.rows.item(i).id + "</b></p>";
     msg = "<p><b>Name :-" + results.rows.item(i).log +"<br/>Contact :-" +results.rows.item(i).id + "</b></p>";
     //var row = result.rows.item(i);
     //msg = console.log("  " + row.contact + " " + row.nam);
     document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
   }
 }, null);
});
}
function ByContact(){
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var con = document.getElementById("Con").value;
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM APP WHERE (id LIKE ?);',[con], function (tx, results) {
  console.log("All rows:");
   var len = results.rows.length, i;
   msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
   document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
     msg = "<p><b>Name :-" + results.rows.item(i).log +"<br/>Contact :-" +results.rows.item(i).id + "</b></p>";
     msg = "<p><b>Name :-" + results.rows.item(i).log +"<br/>Contact :-" +results.rows.item(i).id + "</b></p>";
     //var row = result.rows.item(i);
     //msg = console.log("  " + row.contact + " " + row.nam);
     document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
   }
 }, null);
});
}

</script>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url('f.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;">
<h1 align="center"><font color="white">Contact Form</font></h1>
    <div  style="color:white">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td>contact no</td>
<td><input type="text" id="Tid"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td><input type="text" id="Tname"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<button id="add" onclick="return insert();">Insert</button>
</td>
<td>
<button onclick="return readdata();" id="read">readdata</button>
</td>
<td>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
    <button onclick="return ByContact();" id="GetByContact">GetByContact</button>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" id="Con"/>
    </td>
</tr>

        </table>
        <div id="status" name="status"><font color="white">Your Data`enter code here` Will Show Here</font></div>
</div>       

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible to replace the splash screen image in the emulator or in the App Preview tool. You can only replace the splash screen in an *APK build* that you load onto your device or submit to the Google Play store.

In the current version of the XDK (November, 2013) you provide a custom splash screen image at build time. When you go through the build process you turn your HTML5 app into an APK that can be installed on an Android device or submitted to the store. During this build process there is an "Assets" screen that includes options to submit custom splash screens and a custom icon.

**If you submit these custom images during the build** you will still see the Intel XDK splash screen when you debug your app with App Preview or the built-in emulator. However, when you install the APK that you receive after doing a build it will contain your custom splash screen.

Comment: we can't remove the plash screen , but we can replace it,by go through build option